# SPSS twostep cluster analysis to use with ordinal variables

Tags: clustering, spss, ordinal-data

How do you distinguish between ordinal (ordered) and non-ordinal (nominal) categorical variables when setting up a SPSS Two-step cluster analysis? The procedure seems to have only one undifferentiated input field "categorical variables".

Example of an ordinal variable: 1=low 2=medium 3=high.

Comment: It isn't clear to me exactly what you're asking for here - is it how to know substantively which variables are ordinal and which are not? Or is this about how to use SPSS? The latter is not outside the scope of our site - see our [help/on-topic] for more details.

Comment: TwoStep cluster analysis does not allow ordinal variables. By "categorical" in means nominal only. Consider using your ordinal ones as if they are continuous (which wouldn't great sin for, for example likert type questions). Or refuse doing TwoStep and do Hierarchical cluster, if you number of cases isn't huge. Or you might take the trick to convert your ordinal data first to inteval via optimal scaling of Categorical PCA procedure, then input to TwoStep with clear conscience.

Comment: @Silverfish, this Q is both about SPSS and the method as it exists there.

Comment: @ttnphns In your opinion is there is an underlying statistical issue here, rather than just an SPSS one? I think your edit makes the situation rather clearer (and have retracted my close vote).

Comment: @Silverfish, I think the Q might be kept, because it asks about a data type suitable for a statistical method, although it was worded as SPSS specific question.

Comment: the question is not about knowing how to use SPSS. I know how to use SPSS. All categorical variables are treated as nomial, otherwise they would be scale which is continuous.

What I am asking is, is there anyway within the cluster analysis setup to allowing the method to take the order of ordered categorical variables into account. 

OR is it just treating them as any categorical variable that may be unordered.

Comment: @ttnphns Also, the statement about TwoStep cluster in SPSS not handling ordinal is not true. Please refer to this: https://www.statisticalinnovations.com/wp-content/uploads/Bacher2004.pdf

I am asking how spss recognizes the variable is ordered and if this is taken into account and how to differentiate between ordered and unordered categorical variables

Comment: @msawdey, I can only repeat what I know. The procedure does not recognize ordinal type (it can take ordinal, but doesn't treat them as ordinal, only either as continuous or as nominal). SPSS docs say: "In calculating log-likelihood, normal distributions for continuous variables and _multinomial_ distributions for categorical variables are assumed" (italics mine). If you can show that I'm wrong, please be kind to let us here know.

Comment: @ttnphns I just needed the clarification that was provided in the answer I selected. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would put it differently.  TWOSTEP certainly allows ordinal variables, but it treats them the same as nominal variables.  They are simply assumed to be multinomial.  As ttnphns says, though, treating ordinal variables as continuous might be satisfactory  Clustering is a rather ad hoc technique.  You might also want to consider using a Support Vector Machine (SVM) in unsupervised mode via the STATS SVM extension command.  That procedure distinguishes between ordinal and nominal scales, although unsupervised mode is mainly useful for anomaly detection.

You can install this extension from the Utilities menu in Statistics 22-23 or the Extensions menu in V24.  It requires the R Essentials.

Comment: This is the confirmation I was looking for: " TWOSTEP certainly allows ordinal variables, but it treats them the same as nominal variables. They are simply assumed to be multinomial". Thank you!